# Setting Computer Info Fields with ARD UNIX Command

Tags: macos, unix, redirect

I am trying to change the computer info field of an OS X machine using the below command:

```
    system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/MAC Address:/{print $NF}' | /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set1 -1
```

I am having problems with it and know that the above is not right. Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out:

```
 sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteDesktop \Text1 $(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/MAC Address:/{print $NF}')
```

Restart after using:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent -console
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way for those interested:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set1 -1 $(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/MAC Address:/{print $NF}')
```